# Simulation of RF in CC430F5137 is not working

Tags: msp430

I'm trying to debug the program `RF_Toggle_LED_Demo.c` which is included in [slaa465b.zip](http://www.ti.com/mcu/docs/litabsmultiplefilelist.tsp?sectionId=96&tabId=1502&literatureNumber=slaa465b&docCategoryId=1&familyId=1663) ([SLAA465 - CC430 RF Examples](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa465b/slaa465b.pdf)) via the simulator in IAR for MSP430 ver.5.501.

When I run the program step by step I get stuck at the instruction `SetVCore(2);`

I've tried marking this line as a comment. In that case the simulator get stuck on the following line which is `InitRadio();`.

What is the reason for this? What can I do in order to simulate the program?

**Here is the main file.**

```
/******************************************************************************
*CC430 RF Code Example - TX and RX (variable packet length > FIFO size)
* G. Larmore
* Texas Instruments Inc.
* June 2012
* Built with IAR v5.40.1 and CCS v5.2
******************************************************************************/

#include "RF_Toggle_LED_Demo.h"

extern RF_SETTINGS rfSettings;

unsigned char packetReceived;
unsigned char packetTransmit; 

unsigned char txBytesLeft = PACKET_LEN+1;         // +1 for length byte 
unsigned char txPosition = 0; 
unsigned char rxBytesLeft = PACKET_LEN+2;         // +3 for len & status bytes
unsigned char rxPosition = 0;
unsigned char lengthByteRead = 0; 
unsigned char RxBufferLength = 0;
unsigned char TxBufferLength = 0; 
unsigned char * _p_Buffer = 0; 
unsigned char buttonPressed = 0;
unsigned int i = 0;                 
unsigned char transmitting = 0; 
unsigned char receiving = 0; 
unsigned char RxBuffer[PACKET_LEN+2] = {0};

unsigned char TxBuffer[PACKET_LEN+1]= {
PACKET_LEN, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 
        0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 
        0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 
        0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 
        0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 
        0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 
        0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 
        0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 
        0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89, 
        0x90, 0x91, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 
};

void main( void )
{  
  // Stop watchdog timer to prevent time out reset 
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; 

  // Increase PMMCOREV level to 2 for proper radio operation
  SetVCore(2);                               

  ResetRadioCore();
  InitButtonLeds();
  InitTimer(); 

  // Clean out the RX Buffer 
  rxPosition = PACKET_LEN+2;
  while(rxPosition--)
  {
    RxBuffer[rxPosition] = 0; 
  }

  InitRadio();  
  ReceiveOn(); 

  while (1)
  { 
    P1IE |= BIT7;                           // Enable button interrupt

    __bis_SR_register( LPM3_bits + GIE );   
    __no_operation(); 

    if (buttonPressed)                      // Process a button press->transmit 
    {            
      ReceiveOff();                         // Button means TX, stop RX
      receiving = 0;                         
      TransmitPacket();                 
      buttonPressed = 0;                    // Re-enable button press                           
     }    
    if(receiving)
    {
      ReceivePacket(); 
      __no_operation(); 
    }
    if(!transmitting)
    {
      ReceiveOn(); 
    }
  }
}

void ReceivePacket(void)
{
  rxBytesLeft = PACKET_LEN + 2;// Set maximum packet leng + 2 for appended bytes
  rxPosition = 0; 
  packetReceived = 0; 

  __delay_cycles(2800);                     // Wait for bytes to fill in RX FIFO

  TA0CCR1   = RX_TIMER_PERIOD;              // x cycles * 1/32768 = y us
  TA0CCTL1 |= CCIE;            
  TA0CTL   |= MC_2 + TACLR;                 // Start the timer- continuous mode

  __bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits + GIE); 
  __no_operation(); 

  TA0CCR1 = RX_TIMER_PERIOD;             
  TA0CCTL1 &= ~(CCIE);
  TA0CTL &= ~(MC_3);                  // Turn off timer 

 __no_operation(); 
}

void TransmitPacket(void)
{  
  P3OUT |= BIT6;                        // Pulse LED during Transmit 
  txBytesLeft = PACKET_LEN + 1;   
  txPosition = 0; 
  packetTransmit = 0; 
  transmitting = 1;       

  Strobe( RF_STX );                         // Strobe STX   

  TA0CCR1   = TX_TIMER_PERIOD;              // x cycles * 1/32768 = y us
  TA0CCTL1 |= CCIE; 
  TA0CTL |= MC_2 + TACLR;                   // Start the timer- continuous mode   

  __bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits + GIE); 
  __no_operation(); 

  TA0CCR1 = TX_TIMER_PERIOD;             // x cycles * 1/32768 = y us
  TA0CCTL1 &= ~(CCIE); 
  TA0CTL &= ~(MC_3);                  // Turn off timer         

  P3OUT &= ~BIT6;                     // Turn off LED after Transmit               
}

void ReceiveOn(void)
{  
  RF1AIES &= ~BIT9; 
  RF1AIFG = 0;                              // Clear pending RFIFG interrupts
  RF1AIE  |= BIT9;                          // Enable the sync word received interrupt

  // Radio is in IDLE following a TX, so strobe SRX to enter Receive Mode
  Strobe( RF_SRX );        

  __no_operation(); 
}

void ReceiveOff(void)
{
  RF1AIE &= ~BIT9;                          // Disable RX interrupts
  RF1AIFG &= ~BIT9;                         // Clear pending IFG
  RF1AIES &= ~BIT9;                         // Switch back to to sync word

  // It is possible that ReceiveOff is called while radio is receiving a packet.
  // Therefore, it is necessary to flush the RX FIFO after issuing IDLE strobe 
  // such that the RXFIFO is empty prior to receiving a packet.
  Strobe(RF_SIDLE); 
  Strobe(RF_SFRX);                       
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  void pktRxHandler(void)
//
//  DESCRIPTION:
//      This function is called every time a timer interrupt occurs. The 
//      function starts by retreiving the status byte. Every time the status 
//      byte indicates that there are available bytes in the RX FIFO, bytes are 
//      read from the RX FIFO and written to RxBuffer. This is done until the 
//      whole packet is received. If the status byte indicates that there has 
//      been an RX FIFO overflow the RX FIFO is flushed. Please see the 
//      EM430F5137RF900 RF Examples User Manual for a flow chart describing this 
//      function.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void pktRxHandler(void) {
  unsigned char RxStatus;
  unsigned char bytesInFifo;

  // Which state?
  RxStatus = Strobe(RF_SNOP);

  switch(RxStatus & CC430_STATE_MASK)
  {
    case CC430_STATE_RX:
      // If there's anything in the RX FIFO....
      if (bytesInFifo = MIN(rxBytesLeft, RxStatus & CC430_FIFO_BYTES_AVAILABLE_MASK))
      {         
        if((rxBytesLeft == PACKET_LEN + 2) && !lengthByteRead)
        {
          rxBytesLeft = ReadSingleReg(RXFIFO) + 2;  // For appended bytes
          lengthByteRead = 1; 
        }
        // Update how many bytes are left to be received
        rxBytesLeft -= bytesInFifo;

        // Read from RX FIFO and store the data in rxBuffer
        while (bytesInFifo--) {
          RxBuffer[rxPosition] = ReadSingleReg(RXFIFO);
          rxPosition++; 
    }  
    if (!rxBytesLeft){           
        packetReceived = 1; 
        receiving = 0;
        lengthByteRead = 0; 
        ReceiveOff();

        P1OUT ^= BIT0;                    // Toggle LED1             
    }      
  } 
  break;
default:
  if(!packetReceived)
  {
    packetReceived = 1; 
  }

  rxBytesLeft = 0;
  receiving = 0; 
  ReceiveOff();

  break;  
  }
} // pktRxHandler

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  void pktTxHandler(void)
//  DESCRIPTION:
//  This function is called every time a timer interrupt occurs. The function starts
//      by getting the status byte. Every time the status byte indicates that there 
//      is free space in the TX FIFO, bytes are taken from txBuffer and written to 
//      the TX FIFO until the whole packet is written or the TXFIFO has underflowed. 
//      See the EM430F5137RF900 RF Examples User Manual for a flow chart describing 
//      this function.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void pktTxHandler(void) {
    unsigned char freeSpaceInFifo;
    unsigned char TxStatus;  

// Which state?
TxStatus = Strobe(RF_SNOP);

switch (TxStatus & CC430_STATE_MASK) {
    case CC430_STATE_TX:
        // If there's anything to transfer..
        if (freeSpaceInFifo = MIN(txBytesLeft, TxStatus &                             

CC430_FIFO_BYTES_AVAILABLE_MASK)) 
        {
          txBytesLeft -= freeSpaceInFifo;

          while(freeSpaceInFifo--)
          {
            WriteSingleReg(TXFIFO, TxBuffer[txPosition]);
            txPosition++; 
          }

          if(!txBytesLeft)
          {                
            RF1AIES |= BIT9;      // End-of-packet TX interrupt
            RF1AIFG &= ~BIT9;     // clear RFIFG9
            while(!(RF1AIFG & BIT9)); // poll RFIFG9 for TX end-of-packet  
            RF1AIES &= ~BIT9;      // End-of-packet TX interrupt
            RF1AIFG &= ~BIT9;     // clear RFIFG9
            transmitting = 0; 
            packetTransmit = 1; 
          }
        }
        break;

    case CC430_STATE_TX_UNDERFLOW:
        Strobe(RF_SFTX);  // Flush the TX FIFO

        __no_operation(); 
        // No break here!
    default:
        if(!packetTransmit) 
          packetTransmit = 1; 

        if (transmitting) {
            if ((TxStatus & CC430_STATE_MASK) == CC430_STATE_IDLE) {
              transmitting = 0; 
            }
        }
    break;
}
} // pktTxHandler

void InitTimer(void)
{
  P5SEL |= 0x03;                            // Set xtal pins
  LFXT_Start(XT1DRIVE_0);
  TA0CCR1  = RX_TIMER_PERIOD;               // x cycles * 1/32768 = y us
  TA0CCTL1 = CCIE;                          // Enable interrupts
  TA0CTL   = TASSEL__ACLK + TACLR;          // ACLK source
}

void InitButtonLeds(void)
{
  // Set up the button as interruptible 
  P1DIR &= ~BIT7;
  P1REN |= BIT7;
  P1IES &= BIT7;
  P1IFG = 0;
  P1OUT |= BIT7;
  P1IE  |= BIT7; 

  // Initialize Port J
  PJOUT = 0x00;
  PJDIR = 0xFF; 

  // Set up LEDs 
  P1OUT &= ~BIT0;
  P1DIR |= BIT0;
  P3OUT &= ~BIT6;
  P3DIR |= BIT6;
}

void InitRadio(void)
{
  // Set the High-Power Mode Request Enable bit so LPM3 can be entered
  // with active radio enabled 
  PMMCTL0_H = 0xA5;
  PMMCTL0_L |= PMMHPMRE_L; 
  PMMCTL0_H = 0x00; 

  WriteRfSettings(&rfSettings);
  WriteSinglePATable(PATABLE_VAL);
}

/**************************************
* Interrupt Service Routines
**************************************/

#pragma vector=TIMER0_A1_VECTOR
__interrupt void TIMER0_A1_ISR(void)
{
  switch(__even_in_range(TA0IV,14))
  {
    case 0:  break;                  
    case 2:  
      if(receiving)
      {
        TA0CCR1 += RX_TIMER_PERIOD;      // 16 cycles * 1/32768 = ~500 us
        pktRxHandler();  

    if(packetReceived)
      __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM3_bits); 
  }
  else if(transmitting)
  {
    TA0CCR1 += TX_TIMER_PERIOD;                  // 16 cycles * 1/32768 = ~500 us

    pktTxHandler(); 

    if(packetTransmit)
      __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM3_bits); 
  }       
  break;
    case 4:  break;                         // CCR2 not used
    case 6:  break;                         // Reserved not used
    case 8:  break;                         // Reserved not used
    case 10: break;                         // Reserved not used
    case 12: break;                         // Reserved not used
    case 14: break;                         // Overflow not used
  }
}

#pragma vector=CC1101_VECTOR
__interrupt void CC1101_ISR(void)
{
  switch(__even_in_range(RF1AIV,32))        // Prioritizing Radio Core Interrupt 
  {
    case  0: break;                         // No RF core interrupt pending                                            
    case  2: break;                         // RFIFG0 
    case  4: break;                         // RFIFG1
    case  6: break;                         // RFIFG2
    case  8: break;                         // RFIFG3
    case 10: break;                         // RFIFG4
    case 12: break;                         // RFIFG5
    case 14: break;                         // RFIFG6          
    case 16: break;                         // RFIFG7
    case 18: break;                         // RFIFG8
    case 20:                                // RFIFG9
      if(!(RF1AIES & BIT9))                 // RX sync word received 
      {
        receiving = 1;         
        __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM3_bits); // Exit active    
      }    
      else while(1);                // trap 
      break;
    case 22: break;                         // RFIFG10
    case 24: break;                         // RFIFG11
    case 26: break;                         // RFIFG12
    case 28: break;                         // RFIFG13
    case 30: break;                         // RFIFG14
    case 32: break;                         // RFIFG15
      }      
    }

#pragma vector=PORT1_VECTOR
__interrupt void PORT1_ISR(void)
{
  switch(__even_in_range(P1IV, 16))
  {
    case  0: break;
    case  2: break;                         // P1.0 IFG
    case  4: break;                         // P1.1 IFG
    case  6: break;                         // P1.2 IFG
    case  8: break;                         // P1.3 IFG
    case 10: break;                         // P1.4 IFG
    case 12: break;                         // P1.5 IFG
    case 14: break;                         // P1.6 IFG
    case 16:                                // P1.7 IFG
      __delay_cycles(1000);                 // debounce delay 
      buttonPressed = 1;
      P1IE = 0;                             // Debounce by disabling buttons
      P1IFG = 0; 
      __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM3_bits); // Exit active    
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive when the simulator gets stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Set VCore() is a function that sets the core voltage regarding to the clock frequency.
I am quite sure it looks for some feedback from the hardware to continue. Such as a bit that is set in a register when the voltage is stable.
The simulator may not simulate this behavior and the program get stuck in an infinite loop, waiting on a flag that will never get the correct state.
If you want to simulate this code, you can safely comment the vcore() line. It won't have any effect on the simulated result. Or, if you want to be cleaner, you could perform conditional compilation such as:

```
void main( void )
{  
    // Stop watchdog timer to prevent time out reset 
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; 

#ifdef SIMULATOR
    // Increase PMMCOREV level to 2 for proper radio operation
    SetVCore(2);
#endif                               

    ResetRadioCore();
    InitButtonLeds();
    InitTimer(); 
    ....
```

And then define SIMULATOR in you IDE when the code has to be simulated.

I am also sure that the program hangs on the initRadio for the same reason. It inits the RF part, but the simulator doesn't simulate it correctly and your code is waiting somewhere an answer that will never occur.